# CMake and BLAS for a C program

Tags: c, cmake, blas

I'm trying to use CMake to build a program relying on blas, I'm detecting blas using :

```
include (${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake)
```

The problem is, FindBLAS require a fortran compiler and complain with

```
-- Looking for BLAS... - NOT found (Fortran not enabled)
```

As blas is already installed on my machine (ATLAS Blas), and gfortran is also installed, how can I enable Fortran, or is there a workaround to find the blas library for C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CMake Documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aenable_language) is your friend, what you need is `enable_language`.

Comment: It's no wonder you didn't see it, the CMake documentation is poorly constructed and difficult to read.